# UIImagePickerControllerDelegate to Swift?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller, swift

```
    if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.Camera)
    {

        var imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
        imagePicker.delegate = self
        imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.Camera;
        //imagePicker.mediaTypes = kUTTypeImage
        imagePicker.allowsEditing = false

        self.presentViewController(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }
```

I can't seem to convert to kUTTypeImage to swift, if I comment out this line the camera launches, but the screen is black. Any ideas? This is the objective C syntax:

```
imagePicker.mediaTypes = @[(NSString *) kUTTypeImage];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently it was this simple:

```
if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.Camera)
{
    var imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
    imagePicker.delegate = self
    imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.Camera;
    imagePicker.mediaTypes = [kUTTypeImage]
    imagePicker.allowsEditing = false

    self.presentViewController(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: Yes, because if you look at the Objective-C syntax, `mediaTypes` is an array.

Comment: Yes, I realized that after posting the question.

Comment: Also, you can simplify a line -- `imagePicker.sourceType = .Camera` — when you have a value of an enum type, you only need the distinguishing part of the enum name. (And a dot.)

Comment: Worth noting that `kUTTypeImage` is an optional so you need to unwrap it like so:  `cameraUI.mediaTypes  = [kUTTypeImage!]`

Comment: you need to add this import also:
`import MobileCoreServices`

Answer (score 2):

I have tested those codes in XCode6 beta5, and found the following error:

> fatal error: array element cannot be bridged to Objective-C
>
> Thread 1:EXC_BREAKPOINT(code=EXC_ARM_BREAKPOINT, subcode-0xe7ffdefe)

The reason is that we can't assign an array with objects to *imagePicker.mediaTypes* like this in XCode6 beta5:

```
imagePicker.mediaTypes = [kUTTypeImage]
```

I initialized the array with object through the init function, and it works fine now↓↓↓

```
imagePicker.mediaTypes = NSArray(object: kUTTypeImage)
```

Answer (score 1):

To define `kUTTypeMovie` you could use:

```
imagePicker.mediaTypes = [String(kUTTypeMovie)]
```

Answer (score 0):

To add both movie and image, you could do this.

```
let availableMediaTypes = UIImagePickerController.availableMediaTypesForSourceType(.Camera)
self.imagePickercontroller.mediaTypes = availableMediaTypes!
```

You would notice you could either navigate to a video or capture image button when the imagePickercontroller has been presented. Following that just check the type of mediatype in the delegate method "didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo"

Answer (score 0):

The code marked as the correct answer no longer works in Swift 4+ because some changes have been made.

`UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.Camera` was changed to `UIImagePickerController.SourceType.camera` and `self.presentViewController(...)` to `self.present(...)`

Here is the same code that works for Swift 4+:

```
if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerController.SourceType.camera)
    {

        let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
        imagePicker.delegate = self
        imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerController.SourceType.camera;
        imagePicker.allowsEditing = false

        self.present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }
```